# How do you serialize a fragment of an Xtext parse tree/AST?

Tags: serialization, abstract-syntax-tree, xtext, xtend

I have some xtend code that gets a parse tree/AST from a file in my DSL.

I want a method that will serialize any node in the tree.  This means I want text in the language of my DSL for an EObject somewhere in the parse tree.

So, if a program in my language is

```
class C {
    int foo = 3;
}
```

the parse tree might look like

```
MyProgram
|_ MyClass
   |_MyFieldDecl
     |_Type
     | |_IntType
     |_Identifier
     |_Expression
       |_LiteralInteger
```

If I assigned a variable x the MyFieldDecl object in the tree, then I might want to call

```
var s = serialize(x)
```

to get the String, "int foo = 3;"

So, how do I implement that serialize() function?

The code I find when searching around will serialize the entire tree but not a node/fragment.

I found things in the xtext core code that appear to be doing this with either some instance of ISerializer or GrammarAccessExtensions.  I tried to inject

```
@Inject @Extension GrammarAccessExtensions _grammarAccessExtensions
```

and get the serialization using

```
val s = _grammarAccessExtensions.grammarFragmentToString(e, prefix);
```

where e is an EObject, some node in the parse tree.

That failed on the statement

```
val main = injector.getInstance(MyClass)
```

with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.model.project.IXtextProjectConfig was bound.
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.model.project.IXtextProjectConfig
    for field at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGeneratorNaming.projectConfig(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGeneratorNaming
    for field at org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.grammarAccess.GrammarAccessExtensions._xtextGeneratorNaming(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.grammarAccess.GrammarAccessExtensions
    for field at myorg.MyClass._grammarAccessExtensions(Unknown Source)
  while locating myorg.MyClass

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1004)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at myorg.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:435)
```

I think this means I need to bind or inject things, but I just started working with this code base a couple of days ago, and all of this is new to me.

I also tried to copy code out of the xtext core to get an ISerializer and call

```
s = GrammarAccessExtensions.grammarFragmentToString(serializer, e, prefix)
```

That failed with this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Invalid context: Grammar returns ScenarioModel
```

Comment: where you you get injector from

Comment: `val injector = new ScenarioStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration`

Comment: can you please post a complete sample grammar and java main